# Where can I find Expression Blend 4 for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, expression-blend, expression-blend-4

I wanted to try Expression Blend and found out that the product, Expression Studio, is discontinued. I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and the only thing I can find on the website for Expression (http://www.microsoft.com/expression/) is software for Visual Studio 2012.

Where can I find Expression Blend 4 for Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the MSDN subscription for your VS Ultimate license is still active you can download the old versions from there. If not, then the new ones are your only option, but you *should* still be able to work on your 2010 solution with the newer version of Blend thanks to the round-tripping feature added to VS 2012.

Comment: How can I work with Blend 2012? I load up my VS 2010 wpf application made in .net 4 and I get no design view and I VS 2012 with update 4.